# PyQT5 : why do direct shortcut class works whereas shortcut syntax doesn't work in QAction?

Tags: pyqt5, focus, qaction, qshortcut

I'm facing a weird problem where page changing shortcut works in one syntax and don't in another.

My application has 2 windows, each one on a different screen. The first window displays the main information, and the secondary displays monitoring information. Both windows are independents but should share some common pages (preferences / menu ...). Each window has different pages : some common (menu, preferences), and some of their own (home page...)

Then the structure is a little bit complex : both windows are contained in an object (config), which deals with all the objects of the application.

Both windows inherit of a commun "Windw" class, to share common methods and common pages (home page / preference...). Each window has its own class for all its dedicated variables and objects.

Everything works well for the moment and I try now to create the page's change method. Each page is referenced in a table of contents dictionary which is calling the right content.
The page change method works fine as well.

The problem is related with shortcuts / actions.
If I use this syntax :

```
menu_action = QAction ("Menu", self)
menu_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"))
menu_action.activated.connect(self.page_change)
```

in the WindowPcp class, or with self.pcp when I try to put this code in the Configuration class, "page_change" is not called.

If I use this syntax :

```
menu_short = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m", self)
menu_short.activated.connect(self.page_change)
```

the shortcut behave as expected : the Windwpcp page is changed from home_page to menu page.

Here is a minimal working code of my application skeleton (the real application is too big to be published here (around 2500 lines for all of the windows behavior) :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction,
                             QApplication,
                             QFrame,
                             QHBoxLayout,
                             QLabel,
                             QMainWindow,
                             QShortcut,
                             QStackedLayout,
                             QVBoxLayout,
                             QWidget)


class Windw(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.active_page = "home"

        self.menu = QLabel("Menu")

        m_body = QFrame()
        # Main common Layout
        self.central_layout = QStackedLayout()

        self.menu_page = QFrame()
        menu_page_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.menu_page.setLayout(menu_page_layout)

        self.menu_frame = QFrame()
        self.menu_frame_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.menu_frame.setLayout(self.menu_frame_layout)
        # Adding inner frame to main menu page frame
        menu_page_layout.addWidget(self.menu_frame)

        self.home_page = QFrame()
        self.home_page_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.home_page.setLayout(self.home_page_layout)

        self.preferences = QFrame()
        preferences_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.preferences.setLayout(preferences_layout)

        self.tbl_contents = {"menu": self.menu_page, "home": self.home_page, "preferences": self.preferences}

        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.menu_page)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.home_page)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.preferences)

        m_body.setLayout(self.central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(m_body)

    def page_change(self):
        origine = self.sender()
        print(f"page_changed activated !!!!")
        if origine.objectName() == "menu_short":
            self.active_page = "menu"
            self.central_layout.setCurrentWidget(self.tbl_contents[self.active_page])
        elif origine.objectName() == "home_short":
            self.active_page = "home"
            self.central_layout.setCurrentWidget(self.sommaire[self.page_active])
        elif origine.objectName() == "preferences_short":
            self.active_page = "preferences"
            self.central_layout.setCurrentWidget(self.sommaire[self.page_active])


class WindowPcp(Windw):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.active_page = "home"
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.TabFocus)

        text_pcp = QLabel("Pcp Homepage")

        # Adding content to each pages
        self.menu_frame_layout.addWidget(self.menu)
        self.home_page_layout.addWidget(text_pcp)

        self.central_layout.setCurrentWidget(self.tbl_contents[self.active_page])

        """menu_act = QAction("Menu", self,)
        menu_act.setObjectName("menu_short")
        menu_act.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"))                 # Never works
        menu_act.triggered.connect(self.page_change)"""

        menu_short = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"), self)
        menu_short.setObjectName("menu_short")                       # works as expected
        menu_short.activated.connect(self.page_change)


class WindowScd(Windw):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.active_page = "home"
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        text_scd = QLabel("Scd Homepage")

        # Adding content to each pages
        self.menu_frame_layout.addWidget(self.menu)
        self.home_page_layout.addWidget(text_scd)

        self.central_layout.setCurrentWidget(self.tbl_contents[self.active_page])


class Configuration(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_conf = QGuiApplication.screens()
        self.prim_screen = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()

        self.pcp = WindowPcp()
        self.scd = WindowScd()

        self.pcp.setGeometry(self.screen_conf[1].geometry())
        self.scd.setGeometry(self.prim_screen.geometry())

       # commented lines to compare working and not working syntax :
        """menu_act = QAction("Menu", self.pcp)
        menu_act.setObjectName("menu_short")                     # Never works
        menu_act.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"))
        menu_act.triggered.connect(self.pcp.page_change)"""

        """menu_short = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"), self.pcp)
        menu_short.setObjectName("menu_short")                   # works as expected
        menu_short.activated.connect(self.pcp.page_change)"""


# ------------- MAIN --------------------
app = QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

config = Configuration()  # Configuration object : contains windows and all main objects

config.scd.show()
config.pcp.show()

try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except SystemExit:
    print('windows closed...')
```

I tried to use QActions first, but the shortcut doesn't work. I tried with QShortcut and it works... but the window needs to be in focus... I then tried to put the QShortcut at the Configuration Level to have global control... But QShortcut refusse "self" as the parent object when related to Configuration and only accepts WindwPCP as parent.

Here are my questions :

1. Why does direct QShortcut work and why the QAction shortcut (or more certainly the QAction itself) doesn't ? It's strange to me as other QActions are working inside WindwPCP when used on QPushButtons
2. I really need these shortcuts to work as they will be used by a remote control. Then even if the QShortcut solution works, it isn't good enough for me as the window must be in focus. If focus is changed, I'll loose the remote control of my application. That's why I tried to add the QShortcut in the Configuration class, to be at the top Level of the application. But I'm facing another problem : the QShortcut doesn't work if I replace `menu_short = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"), self.pcp)` with `menu_short = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+m"), self)`

The shortcut doesn't work on the config object itself (Configuration class), it only accepts my windows as a parent.
Is there a way to have a global level of shortcuts, which I'll then filter, to send them to the right objects in order to avoid to have to deal with the focus ?

3. If nothing for 2) is possible, as I don't need remote control for the second window which will be used by a touchscreen, is there a way to force the focus on WindwPCP, without loosing control on its inside widgets ? setFocusPolicy on both windows doesn't seem ti be enough for the moment...

Thank you for your time and help : I'm really stuck at the moment...

Comment: See: [QShortcut.context](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#context-prop) and [Qt.ShortcutContext](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum).

Comment: Your `Configuration` class is useless as a QWidget, and you're not considering the context of the shortcut as suggested above by ekhumoro: as the documentation explains, the default context is the window. Also, your windows do not share common pages (which would be impossible), they have different instances of common classes, which is a completely different thing. Besides, all that is completely irrelevant to the issue: your problem has absolutely nothing to do with how or what each window shows, but how the shortcuts are handled.

Comment: @ekhumoro : I'll try tomorrow if I have time. I saw QShortcut.context in the documentation, but the explanation wasn't really clear to me... your Qt.ShortcutContext link is clearer, and seems to be the right way to go. The books I have and the examples I've seen here didn't emphasize that there were multiple spectrum levels for shortcuts. Thank you very much for your answer. I'll keep this question updated after my tests.

Comment: @musicamante : Thank U for your answer. I didn't know about the different contexts. I saw the method in the class description, but the detail was obscur to me and I didn't realize the problem was there.
I only published a summary of my whole code (more than 2500 lines), then yes, Configuration is useless in this example...  but contains a lot more in my application (QMediaPlayer, relay signals between objects, error log...). As I didn't know where the problem was, I publish a structure example in case the error wasn't shortcut related. Maybe another class instead of QWidget would be better

Comment: @musicamante : You're right regarding the "shared pages", they are different objects... It was just a bad shortcut to explain why I inherited both windows from the main one... : my application will display a menu and a preference page which will look the same on both windows, and different "home page" for each of them. I   explained this point in case somebody could tell me it was the core of my problem, or if it was maybe a wrong approach for my use.

Comment: @Sestifer The [`context`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#context-prop) property documentation provides a direct link (actually, three) to that of `Qt.ShortcutContext`. If you used the PyQt or PySide (aka, "Qt for Python") documentation, the general suggestion is to not consider them, except for special cases in which the Python behavior has differences from the C++ one; as a rule of thumb, always use the C++ API docs as primary resource. On the fact that you weren't sure about where the problem was, that's the reason for which we normally require to provide a [mre]: try to reduce your code »

Comment: @Sestifer until you reach the point where you removed anything that isn't really required to *reproduce* the problem, so that it becomes as short as possible ("*minimal*"). I understand that you may not be experienced enough, but in reality your problem could have been shown with less than 20 lines of code (instead of almost 150): two windows, a shortcut, and a function connected to the `activated` shortcut signal, which could just have been a simple lambda with a `print()`. Take for instance your `Windw`: you already know that the shortcut is not triggered if `"page_changed activated"` is »

Comment: @Sestifer » not shown, meaning that the whole stacked layout is pointless to the problem, because the issue presents itself even before it: which means that it, along with all those inner frames, are completely irrelevant to the problem. You are not sure? Try it! That's how most of debugging is achieved: reduce the context to the *actual* problem, discarding everything else. Now, your explanation about the `Configuration` class still doesn't explain the requirement of a QWidget: QMediaPlayer alone doesn't require a widget, nor signal relaying or error logging. It seems like you're using it »

Comment: @Sestifer » as some sort of "Controller", which is not an *actual widget* (a visual representation reacting to user events), but a *manager* object. In these cases, the common convention is to subclass QApplication and its instance as a "controller", instead of a standard QApplication instance. Alternatively, you can use a QObject subclass for special cases (if it needs Qt features like signals, otherwise a basic Python class will suffice). Still, unless you actually have a *main*, *unique* and *visible* window that controls the whole program, subclassing from QWidget is completely pointless.